# Why is k-means clustering the observations rather than the variables in R?

Tags: r, plot, cluster-analysis, visualization, k-means

I have a dataset `mydata` with 84 variables each with 300 observations, as shown below:

[image]

I am using the following code to cluster `mydata` in 5 clusters:

```
mydata <- read.csv("mydata.csv", header = TRUE)

# K-Means Clustering with 5 clusters
fit <- kmeans(mydata, 5)

# Cluster Plot against first 2 principal components

# vary parameters for most readable graph
library(cluster) 
clusplot(mydata, fit$cluster, color=TRUE, shade=TRUE, labels=2, lines=0)
```

This produces the following plot:[image]

I expected it to plot the 84 variables with their names, as shown in the first image, based on the observations. But instead, as can be seen in the last image, it is clustering the 300 observations. How to fix this?

I tried transposing `mydata`, but that doesn't solve the issue.

**EDIT:** I expected it to plot something like this (but this plot is for another dataset). I show this plot only to show the names of the variables on the plot, which means the variables are getting plotted (based on observations).
[image]

Comment: That is what k-means does.  It clusters observations.  Why would you think it does something different?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Please try to understand the question I am asking. I have also included a sample cluster in the edit to make you understand my point.

Comment: Gordon answered your question correctly. When using a whole bunch of variables it clusters the entity, the observation, based on their global relatedness through you variables. If you want each variable clustered separately, you need to break up your data in your code to present each variable separately

Comment: I think you are looking for methods like principle components analysis (PCA) or factor analysis.

Comment: Following up on @lmo suggestion. You could have a look at this [R-Bloggers article on PCA](https://www.r-bloggers.com/principal-component-analysis-using-r/).

Comment: I don't understand this. Say I have 4 things to cluster (say, flowers), and there are 100 different features (smell, colour, size, texture, etc etc). So, when I take measurements for these, I will have 4 variables and 100 observations, right? Then, when I cluster them, I expect the algorithm to cluster the 4 flowers into 1 or 2 clusters based on the 100 observations of each. Not the other way round - i.e., cluster 100 observations based on 4...whatever it would be perceiving these 4 as. Is it not?

Comment: I think you should read this:  [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) : *"... k-means clustering aims to partition n observations into k clusters in which each observation belongs to the cluster with the nearest mean, serving as a prototype of the cluster ..."*

Comment: @KoenV So, in the above example, when I feed 100 observations for 4 flowers, k-means will not cluster the 4 flowers into 1 or 2 clusters, but rather it will cluster the 100 observations?! If yes, based on what? And how do I cluster the 4 flowers into 2 groups then?

Comment: Yes, is the answer to your first question. Please read **[this on CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/clustering-variables-based-on-correlations-between-them)** for your second question. I hope this helps clarifying and getting you started.

Comment: If you have only 4 things to cluster, kmeans is the wrong tool. In the conventional notation, you would cluster *rows*by least-squares. If you want to cluster columns, transpose into rows first.

Answer (score 2):

If you want **to cluster variables, not instances**, you can simply **transpose** your data matrix.

Usually, clustering is applied to data points, not columns.

Beware of the usual limitations of k-means. It is very sensitive to scale.

Comment: What error does it give? Did you try to fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

The plot you mention had probably been created by using the `mtcars` dataset:

```
print(datasets::mtcars)
```

The points you see are clearly observations.

If you want to create a cluster of variables, multiple options exists:

- Create a matrix of distance between your variables, for exemple with `cor` and do a hierarchical clustering with `hclust`.
- Do a pca then cluster the projection of your variable on the created components. That way, you can use `kmeans` to cluster your variables.
- If all your variables are numeric, you can transpose your dataframe and do a k-mean clustering.

Also, the question of why you want to cluster the variables probably need some more thought.

Comment: I don't understand this. Say I have 4 things to cluster (say, flowers), and there are 100 different features (smell, colour, size, texture, etc etc). So, when I take measurements for these, I will have 4 variables and 100 observations, right? Then, when I cluster them, I expect the algorithm to cluster the 4 flowers into 1 or 2 clusters based on the 100 observations of each. Not the other way round - i.e., cluster 100 observations based on 4...whatever it would be perceiving these 4 as. Is it not?

Comment: I printed the `mtcars` dataset. What it is plotting is certainly the car names (i.e., the variables) based on the features like mpg, cyl, disp, etc (i.e., the observations), and not the other way round.

Comment: Car names is a qualitative variable. Your observations could have one of the modalities of that variable. I prefer to use feature only in the case of modeling context, as it makes things complex otherwise ☺

Comment: I am not a statiscian, so I do not know much about all that. All that I am bothered about is, that in the car dataset, it classifies cars and not the features; while in my dataset, it classifies the features and not the actual variables. Why is that? That's all I wanted to know, and how to fix it.

Comment: The comments of @KoenV are very good and should be the answer, in fact.